# OAuth Popup in Ember.js error

Tags: javascript, twitter, ember.js, ember-cli, oauth.io

I create a simple ember.js app with the newest ember-cli. In a simple function I call:

```
OAuth.initialize('my public key');
```

After that I execute the following code:

```
OAuth.popup('twitter').done(function(twitter) {
        console.log(twitter);
    }).fail(function(err) {
        console.log('It didnt Worked');
    });
```

The popup opens and I can login with my twitter account. Then the popup closes but in the javascript console I see the following error:

```
Could not retrieve methods TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
at Object.module.exports.providers_api.generateMethods (http://localhost:8000/oauth.js:573:30)
at http://localhost:8000/oauth.js:967:17
at _fulfilled (http://localhost:8000/oauth.js:6263:54)
at Promise.then.Q.nextTick.self.promiseDispatch.done (http://localhost:8000/oauth.js:6292:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (http://localhost:8000/oauth.js:6225:13)
at http://localhost:8000/oauth.js:6033:44
at runSingle (http://localhost:8000/oauth.js:5566:13)
at MessagePort.flush (http://localhost:8000/oauth.js:5554:13)
```

And the OAuth promise never gets resolved. The error happens on line 977 in the oauth.js of the OAuth.io Javascript SDK.

I'm using the following verisons:

```
☮ ember -v
version: 1.13.8
node: 0.12.4
npm: 2.13.4
os: darwin x64
//OAuth installed via bower
OAuth.io: "oauth.io#~0.4.3"
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad. The error doesn't crash the popup function and the promises get's resolved. I once again learned this != this. Stupid me.